# Error during ati radeon x600 driver

Tags: graphics

I get this error message during installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about installing the AMD graphics drivers. The open source drivers that come with Elementary OS are the best AMD graphics drivers. What you are trying to install is too old and no longer supported.

You may also update your kernel and see how that works for you.

Alright, buckle up your big boy pants because you are going balls deep today!

We get to play with the terminal. This guide is made assuming that you can get to the terminal [(edit) and the Desktop GUI.] Here is a list of commands that will set you up and upgrade your kernel.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install ukuu`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

- Now go ahead and use UKUU to update the kernel to 4.11.3
- It will say that there are errors the first time you try this, ignore
  that.
- Reboot your computer.
- Go back to UKUU and reinstall 4.11.3 kernel
- If the install was successful, go ahead and restart your computer
  again.

Now run

`sudo apt-get purge ukuu`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

If you only have access to the terminal use this advice given from Lemonslice

As a **workaround**, you might want to try to install 4.11 from the Ubuntu mainline kernels. 
You can download and install from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11.4/ the following packages:

```
sudo dpkg --install linux-headers-4.11.4-041104_4.11.4-041104.201706071003_all.deb \
linux-headers-4.11.4-041104-generic_4.11.4-041104.201706071003_amd64.deb \
linux-image-4.11.4-041104-generic_4.11.4-041104.201706071003_amd64.deb
```

Now restart your computer when your kernel is installed and continue on.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

- Now reboot your computer again for good measure.

When you computer has restarted go ahead and run

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

- Say yes to any prompts.
- Reboot your computer and now try your multimedia keys and possibly
  your video drivers.

I have to do this for my laptop and desktop for it to fully function. The 4.11.3 kernel is really good and has not given me issues.

So yeah, it seems like a lot, you can do it. Have confidence!

Comment: It seems that source drivers dont work very well. Videos showing weird lines. Is there any current driver?

Comment: Its like videos loosing frames . Doesn look smooth...

Comment: Updated my answer. Try updating the kernel.

Comment: I instralled  4.11.3 kernel without any problems. However this did not fix the issue!

OS: elementary OS 0.4.1 loki
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.11.3-041103-generic
Uptime: 7m
Packages: 1971
Shell: bash 4.3.48
Resolution: 3840x1080
WM: Mutter(Gala)
WM Theme: elementary
CPU: Intel Core2 Quad CPU Q9400 @ 2.668GHz
GPU: AMD/ATI RV370 [Radeon X600/X600 SE]
RAM: 1304MiB / 7981MiB

Comment: As soon as i view one youtube video my cpu goes wild from 67-86%

Comment: That could be dependent on your browser. I use Chrome, what do you use? Otherwise, try it on Firefox.   sudo apt-get install firefox